# People API in Microsoft Graph not returning the updated results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We recently updated the profile information in Azure active directory. when we use People API in graph explorer, it is not returning the latest information. How much time does it take normally to return the updated information?

Answer (score 0):

The /me/people API is actually returning from a search index, not a real-time fetch from Azure Active Directory directly. The search index update depends on many characteristics of your AAD. It is safe to say you should see this reflected within 24 hours.

Obviously there is value in the people API with its underlying logic. If you wish to have the data updated instantly. You should use the /users/ to fetch the latest content.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. But the problem it is taking more than 24 hours (sometimes 36 or 48 hours) to fetch the latest content. Unfortunately we can't use /users/ as we are dependant on people API for other functionalities. By any chance can we update search index through PS or some jobs?

Comment: With our tenant it is always taking more than 48 hours.

Comment: There is no way to update the refresh rate right now. There is a lot of work behinds the scenes around Microsoft Search that will impact indexing so hopefully this will get better. If you want to provide actual request ids and examples where it hasn't updated after 48 hours, i'd really appreicate it.