# Microsoft Graph API outdated data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting outdated data from people endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/
```

Returns outdated information for example, for `department` field.

I checked Office365 Admin Portal, Delve, and Azure AD users, the three of them show different information compared to Graph Api.

Tried different ways of querying the same endpoint, searching for a particular user or a list, both scenarios return outdated data.

Comment: Seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305121/people-api-in-microsoft-graph-not-returning-the-updated-results

Comment: It might be, but it's been 5 days so far, pretty long span for an index to update.